# How to redirect HTTP to HTTPS on IIS 6 with multiple directories?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, iis, iis-6

I have a Website (Staging.my.website.edu) created with multiple sub directories as viewed in the following screen shot:
[image]

**What I am trying to do is redirect http://Staging.my.website.edu to https://Staging.my.website.edu including any sub directories that fall under it.**

I tried using the article below and while it did redirect http://Staging.my.website.edu to https://Staging.my.website.edu it did not do the same for https://Staging.my.website.edu/**advlp** directories

I tried using the following link:
http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/dorr/2009/01/13/how-to-force-redirection-from-http-to-https-on-iis-60/

Please let me know if you need anymore information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer in this link: http://www.jppinto.com/2009/01/automatically-redirect-http-requests-to-https-on-iis-6/